# Spring actuator CompositeHealthIndicator - how to automatically use/display all indicators on /health

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring being all auto auto-magic, I was a bit suprised at how I am observing the HealthIndicator to function.

I expected that, when I have a `HealthIndicator` bean in context that it will aggregate it along with the other ones it has and produce a summary in `/actuator/health`. Instead what it does it ignore all the ones *but* my custom one. I ended up implementing my own endpoint aggregating them.

I must be missing something. Either I am not enabling this functionality correctly (and I admit it's confusing) or I am expecting behavior that isn't what it actually should do.

**My Question:** Are my expectations correct? If So, how do I make it auto-aggregate? If my expectations are incorrect, what's the idiomatic way for actuator to work as I desire?

Here is my sample code:

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

  @Override
  public Health health() {
    return Health.up().withDetail("hello","world").build();
  }
}
```

> /actuator/health

```
{
"status": "UP"
}
```

It's also not printing "hello" : "world" as I would have expected but that's another matter.

Here is my custom controller and output:

```
@RestController
public class CustomController {

  private final Map<String,HealthIndicator> indicators;

  @Autowired
  public HealthController(Map<String, HealthIndicator> indicators) {
    this.indicators = indicators;
  }

  @GetMapping("/health")
  public Health getHealth(@RequestParam("deep") Boolean deep){
    if(deep != null && deep)
      return new CompositeHealthIndicator(new OrderedHealthAggregator(),indicators).health();

    return Health.up().build();
  }
}
```

> /health?deep=true

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "helloWorldHealthIndicator": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "hello": "world"
      }
    },
    "diskSpaceHealthIndicator": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 74865782784,
        "free": 65754009600,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "dbHealthIndicator": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "MySQL",
        "hello": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think your custom `HealthIndicator` is not invoked? Have you tried to run an app with the debugger to check if it was invoked?

That output doesn't tell us anything: you may simply get the summarized view of all the health indicators (no detail at all)

The [doc states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health)

> Health information is collected from all HealthIndicator beans defined in your ApplicationContext. Spring Boot includes a number of auto-configured HealthIndicators and you can also write your own.

That code above should work just fine. My best guess is that the details aren't displayed (check the doc to enable that and please note that they are differences between Spring Boot 1 and Spring Boot 2).

Edit: To demonstrate that, I've created [a sample project](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-custom-health-indicator) that [uses the exact same code as yours](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-custom-health-indicator/blob/489aa1b6f7036280e9db110bb4dccae49c38dcbe/src/main/java/com/example/demo/HelloWorldHealthIndicator.java) and I get this when I invoke `health` (with security disabled so that details are shown to anonymous users):

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "helloWorld": {
    "status": "UP",
    "hello": "world"
  },
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 499963170816,
    "free": 217149034496,
    "threshold": 10485760
  }
}
```

Comment: Some how you totally missed the part where I wrote: `..what it does it ignore all the ones but my custom one.`

Comment: I did not because that's not what it is supposed to happen (and you didn't answer my question. Have you tried?). I've edited my answer with a sample that demonstrates what I meant.

Comment: To answer your question specifically: I know my custom health indicator is being invoked. That's not my question. I expected actuator to invoke my stuff and aggregate it with the others on `/actuator/health` and it doesn't. It only shows mine even though the others are in context

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno As Stephane said, it shows the "aggregated" status, as expected. You're just not seeing the details for each indicator (provided and custom ones).

Comment: I get-ya. Time to go find out how to get details. Thanks.

Comment: The details are only displayed when authenticated, or configured so that the details aren't considered to be sensitive.